# Storing date in structure in C

Tags: c, date

I have to write program that works with structures and files. One field in structure must be birthday, so I need to get day, month and year in one field. And I think that I'll need to check if the date is correct. (User inputs the date)

What is the best way to work with date? Do I need to use string in form like dd.mm.yyyy? Or make another structure as a birthday field?
There won't be further processing of the date, only saving in file, opening and showing on screen.

Comment: Do for no matter use any string format to store a date/time. Due to lots of different ways around the world to interpret dates/times stored as string, there is big chance of missunderstanding. Also performance could be an issues when procsessing lots of dates/times available as strings only.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to not implement something yourself, but use predefined libraries. In glibc, for example, there is the `struct tm` structure in `time.h` and many functions to manipulate it (transformations, printing, etc).

See the `ctime(3)` man page.

Comment: time.h is even standard ISO C, so it is a good idea to use those functions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_operations

Answer (score -1):

The standard way is [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), where you count time in seconds as the difference from a reference date. In this case it's January 1st, 1970 (UTC).

The standard library provides lots of functions to deal with time like this, including converting it to a formatted string and the type `time_t`.

Comment: So for people born before January 1st, 1970 (UTC), what happens? (I know it, but the way you phrase it makes it seem like you can't handle this case)

Comment: @user646263: If using UINX time (seconds since epoch) make sure time_t is declared 64bits, if it's not or unsure use your own type for being declare as signed 64bit value. The 32bit time_t is going to overflow quite soon.